# After click link how to trigger onclick on another page by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a question.
Let's say I've got two pages.
On first page I've got link:

```
<a href="www.secondpage.com#changefirst">
```

And on the second page, I've got

```
<p onclick="changeVisibility('#point_4')" id="changefirst></p>
<div id="point_4"></div>
```

And I've got a lot of paragraphs on my second page.
How can I trigger on the second page that if there's a link with specific "#" then when the second page load specific paragraph is onclick triggered?

I was trying to make something with:

```
$('#changefirst').trigger('click');
```

or with:

```
if (hash) {
    $('#changefirst').trigger('click');
}
```

but it's not working, I dunno if I'm going a right way.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: is `$('#changefirst').trigger('click');` already inside document.ready?

Comment: Hi try $('#changefirst').click();

Comment: @ACD when I use document ready its trigger click no matter I get to site via www.secondpage.com#changefirst or www.secondpage.com

Comment: @David check my answer

Comment: I have some question. 1. is that `p` tag take time to load on page?  2. you wan to auto click the element when it's available on page?

Comment: @ShirishPatel 
There's a <ol> with <li> elements. Each <li> element have <p> element and each <p> element have <div> element. <div> elements are hidden. They are shown when we click <p> element. They take some time to load, but it's probably v. short time.

Comment: You mean to say jQuery click is not working once you click?

Comment: I mean when I access site from index.htm#point_4 or index.htm#changefirst it doesnt trigger script. 
I want to make that if user acess from index.htm then nothing happen but when he enter from link with ID (index.htm#point_4 or index.htm#changefirst) then jquery trigger click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @Bhaskara Arani worked but **without the hash "#"** for me.

So this worked:

```
var urlHashVal = window.location.hash;
$(urlHashVal).click();
```

The `.hash` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash) shows that the **"#" is already include**d (thanks Jason).

Comment: Editing this answer and a dding a note about how `.hash` includes the `#` character would be educational and improve this answer. This would even be an appropriate time to link to documentation showing that like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

Comment: Ok, so I pick your anwser then.

Answer (score 1):

You're triggers should be inside document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash === "changefirst")
       $('#changefirst').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but something is wrong with my code above probably and its still not working

Comment: it's working I have to change it like that:
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#changefirst")
       $('#changefirst').click();
});

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
var urlHashVal = window.location.hash;
$("#"+urlHashVal).click();
```